# Centering an image and making it fit to the screen on a website (Very simple)

Tags: html, css, image, web

I am trying to have my image be centered and fit to the screen of the device. So far it is working perfectly fine on mobile because of their portrait orientation but on desktops you have to scroll to see the whole image.

Here is my site with the image [Click Here](http://www.grantbirki.me/The-Canyon.html)

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Outdoor Photography</title>
<link rel="icon" href="site-icon.png">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="Grant Birkinbine, Birki, Grant, Photography, Outdoors" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>

        <img src="/images/The-Canyon.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  /* Smaller Devices */
  img{
    width: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: cover;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 374px) and (max-width: 376px) {
  /* iPhone 6 */
  img{
    width: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: cover;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 319px) and (max-width: 321px) {
  /* iPhone 5 */
  img{
    width: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: cover;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 359px) and (max-width: 361px) {
  /* Galaxy S7 */
  img{
    width: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: cover;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  /* Desktops */
  img {
  width: cover ;
  max-width: 100% ;
  height: cover ;
  }
  .resize {
   width: 1024px; /* 1024 */
   height: auto; /* 682 */  
  }


  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1260px;
    height: 1365px;
    line-height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px solid red;
   }


}

body {
   background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rules to your img style

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: inherit;
```

Answer (score 0):

width and height with cover property value? I don't believe those are valid values. Chrome complains anyway.

From a HTML point of view I would recommend a div with it's css style setting the background-size mode to cover.

Try this as your DIV style and play with background-position:

```
background-image: url(/images/The-Canyon.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position-y: 0%;
```

Answer (score 0):

To display image in full screen without changing the aspect ratio make the image `position:fixed` with `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;` which makes your image fit to the screen

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
img{
    width: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: cover;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Outdoor Photography</title>
<link rel="icon" href="site-icon.png">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="Grant Birkinbine, Birki, Grant, Photography, Outdoors" />
</head>
<body>

        <img src="http://www.grantbirki.me/images/The-Canyon.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 options, you can go the background image route, which will crop it when in a larger screen, but overall looks nicer in my opinion. Or the centered floating image.

**Background image route**

HTML

```
<div class="fill-screen"></div>
```

CSS

```
.fill-screen{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-image:url("http://www.grantbirki.me/images/The-Canyon.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jd3tz338/)**

**Centered image route**
HTML

```
<body><img src="/images/The-Canyon.jpg"></body>
```

CSS

```
img{
  height:100vh;
  width:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  }
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uz471ze1/)**

Comment: I copy and pasted your code exactly how it is and my screen just turned grey as if the only command that executed was background-color. Is there something more I have to do than just copy and paste this info??

Comment: @Birki, nope that should be it. Check above where you pasted it, there may not be a closed tag. Also, these are 2 separate solutions, so it's one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at object-fit : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/  /  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```css
html,
body,
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  object-fit: contain;
  display:block;
}
/* or 
 body{
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: contain;
  display:block;
}
*/
```

```html
<img src="http://www.grantbirki.me/images/The-Canyon.jpg">
```

You play snippet in full page and resize browser to see behavior or play with : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBqOLa